# Mono on the iPhone?

Tags: .net, iphone, mono, clr

Has Mono been ported to the iPhone yet? I'd love to write .NET apps for the iPhone, and learning Objective C isn't an option for me.

Comment: Please elaborate on why learning Objective-C "isn't an option" and what you feel you'd achieve by writing .NET applications instead of applications using the iPhone's native frameworks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, considered getting an iPhone to start writing code for it about August last year. Then three things happened: I looked at iPhone code, I read stories about developing for the iPhone and Android was released. Bye bye iPhone!!!

Comment: @jcollum, I hope you enjoy developing for < 1 million phones vs > 10 million. This may change, but the iPhone is development choice at the moment I would say.

Comment: You should change your accepted answer.  The facts have changed since this was asked.

Comment: @rustyshell, amazing how things change eh? ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Mono today is available in two forms:

- Mono with bindings to iOS APIs per http://monotouch.net
- Mono as a scripting engine powering Unity3D

Comment: Unfortunately licensing of Xamarin (that your link point to) is not good for us. Are there any chance to run .Net on iOS without Xamarin?

Comment: @user695797 well.. open source or license mono from xamarin.. One or the other license should cover all delployments ( Or you can talk directly with xamarin like my company did )

Answer (score 17):

Sorry but not completely true:
http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone

Comment: It's as good as true. That just sounds painful compared to just learning Objective-C. My favourite part is:
    *  A significant amount of cross-compilation is required, this is far from easy.
    * No iPhone APIs have been exposed, so you get the very basic foundation.

Comment: In addition to the fact that you _must_ program on a Mac and _must_ belong to Apple's Developer program. It's nive to be able to program against something you know, but if you're most of the way there already (and Apple _may not_ accept your code because you're using development tools not written by them), then you may as well do it "the right way" via Objective C.

Answer (score 8):

We are developing a [Cocoa Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch) binding called [MonoTouch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#MonoTouch) and a full-[AOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Code_Execution_Engine) toolchain that will allow building native iPhone apps using Mono and [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop). This will be a commercial product, with a beta planned for August. Stay tuned!

Miguel has [blogged about this](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Jun-29.html).

Answer (score 5):

For the nay-sayers, please [listen to Miguel de Icaza](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=157) himself talking about the subject with [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) on the 24NOV2008 [Hanselminutes](http://hanselminutes.com/) podcast (around the 23:50 mark).

Long story short: there are plans to get Silverlight applications statically compiled to conform to Apple's requirements.
You won't be able to run them in the browser but they would be fully integrated iPhone apps just like any others.

Comment: And how would that get around the official App Store restrictions that say you cannot use an interpreter that does not come with the phone?

You can do anything on a Jailbroken phone of course, but presumably that is not what he is looking for.

Comment: Well, you should listen to the show. The key point is that your application would be __statically compiled__ and would become just another native application.

Comment: You use AOT to pre-compile the code, so it is no longer JIT compiled.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a  blog entry](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Mar-10.html) from Miguel de Icaza showing Mono running on the iPhone

(I suspect it's a jailbroken phone, and KiwiBastard's  probably quite correct about the changes of it ever being official)

Answer (score 3):

[First Mono game hits the Apple AppStore.](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Jan-06-1.html)  So, not only is it technically possible, Apple will approve them as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Mono runtime doesn't actually run on those games; it's fully translated to native code.

Answer (score 3):

This allows you to use C# for iPhone now (just recently released, I think), but you still have to have a Mac.

http://monotouch.net/

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked over and over and over again. If you want to write official apps for the iPhone you need to:

- have a real Mac
- learn Objective-C and [Cocoa Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch)
- drink the kool-aid

Trying to work around any of the above is a waste of your time and ours. As I've said many times before it's Steve's way or the highway, and if you want to develop on the iPhone you'd best learn that lesson sooner rather than later.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Steve's way or highway?

Comment: Good point, I fixed the type...though 'of' maybe works as well, since Steve probably would have built the highway in the first place...

Comment: Oh and also be willing to risk your time coming to naught when the iPhone store team rejects your code or determines that Apple is about to release its own version of your app.

Comment: I think what it comes down to at this stage is that there is a lot of money to be made, so people put up with the way Apple treats them. As the store gets more and more crowded, this will no doubt change. But since it's the only way to reach x million iPhones, then you have to play the game :)

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch

MonoTouch allows developers to create C# and .NET based applications that run on the iPhone and can take advantage of the iPhone APIs as well as reusing both code and libraries that have been built for .NET as well as existing skills.

Has no reflection or JIT.

This development on mono for iphone was showcased at microsoft PDC 2008 by Miguel de Icaza

video available here: http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC54/

Answer (score 0):

Never say never, but as it would require a runtime to be running too, I can't see it ever happening. Apple would have to sanction and install the mono/.net runtime with the standard firmware. Same goes for Java too I guess...

Comment: However, we have jailbroken iPhones too!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, kid, but Obj-C is the only way. Why is it "not an option"?

Your app will be "not an option" to Apple for the App Store unless it's written in Obj-C on Xcode, and signed properly.