# Is there a way to make applications in C# for iphone

Tags: c#, iphone

I was wondering if you can make C#/.NET applications for iPhone? How would I start?

Comment: @MarcGravell but it requires Mac anyway. Apple licence - AFAIR.

Comment: Downvoted because the question doesn't show any [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+iphone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) effort.

Comment: There is no way into the App Store without an Apple license.  You can engage consultants or some other company to do that for you, but someone needs to have it.   Mono doesn't provide emulators, so you need a Mac to do any real iPhone app (where you might want to run it before submitting to the App Store)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mono on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377116/mono-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 7):

[Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) would be the way to go .

p.s. i really suggest you go native on any platform .

Answer (score 5):

You can use MonoTouch http://xamarin.com/monotouch

Answer (score 5):

Get yourself a [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) license.

Answer (score 2):

I  recommend you to buy a book for [developing iphone applications using c#](http://www.apress.com/9781430231745)

or go for [Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)